# TYPO3 TypoScript Object in Fluid template as if condition not working

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript

I get my data here:

```
lib.registriernummer = COA_INT
lib.registriernummer {
  10 = TEXT
  10.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|registriernummer
  10.stdWrap.ifEmpty = empty
}
```

In my fluid template I can use:

`{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.registriernummer') -> f:format.raw()}`

which outputs '33'.

If I use the condition:

```xml
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.registriernummer') -> f:format.raw()} == '33'">
  <f:then>
    number is correct
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    number is not correct
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

the output is `number is not correct` . Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried these variants?

```xml
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.registriernummer')->f:format.raw()} == 33">

<f:if condition="'{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:\'lib.registriernummer\')->f:format.raw()}' == '33'">
```

---

As the information for the compare can't be cached, the resulting block can't be cached too.

Either put the block in the (typoscript) viewhelper or make the template uncached.

something like this:

```
lib.registriernummer = COA_INT
lib.registriernummer {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = number is not correct
  10.override = number is correct
  10.override.if.equals.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|registriernummer
  10.override.if.value = 33
}
```

probably you will do more than just some text. ;-)

Comment: The first one is always false, the second always true.

Comment: why do you use the `format.raw` viewhelper? a simple number or string should not need any formatting.

Comment: Problem seems to be the COA_INT-cObject. When using a COA object instead, the condition will match. Don't know why....

Comment: this might be the internal handling of cached and uncached data in TYPO3. uncached data is represented by a placeholder and replaced last minute. maybe the `COA_INT` just delivered this placeholder and your compare never can be equal

Comment: @Bernd: without the format.raw viewhelper i would get <!-- INT_* -->. Yes I tried your variants before, but with no success of building a working condition.
@ Julian and Bernd: Yes, the problem is the COA_INT-cObject because it will be recreated on each page call. Neverthess this worked in TYPO3 8... I just would like to know why and how to solve this issue. Related: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/37988

Comment: `<!-- INT_...-->` is exact the marker for uncached content. but as this information is user specific you need it uncached. in this way the dependend block also needs to be uncached.

Comment: yes i am aware of  the COA_INT delivering uncached data. This way any fe_user from the same group will not see the cached number.  what do you mean by "the dependend block also needs to be uncached" ?

Comment: the output (it's not only the fluid, which is cached) must be uncached. I enhanced my answer with a pure typoscript solution.

Comment: Thanks, but both conditions you proposed do not work, despite the fact that {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.registriernummer')} returns 33.

Comment: the VH does not return `33`. It returns a marker, which is replaced before outputing the page. As this marker never is equal to `33` the compare always is `false` .